# How to give Chrome Extension ability to Search a certain site

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-addons

I'm trying to make a Chrome browser extension that lets you search my site. The search box on the site works. But when I add that same HTML code into my extension file, it doesn't work. Here is the code for my search box:

```html
<form class="text-center" id="searchGuides" action="https://www.arcanumgaming.com/game" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="a" value="search" />
     <input type="hidden" name="g" value="grand-theft-auto-v" />
     <div >
            <input type="text" name="searchVal" class="searchField" placeholder="Search Game Content"  />
     </div>
     <div >
            <a href="#" class="searchBtn" onclick="document.getElementById('searchGuides').submit();">Search Content</a>
     </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. `<button onclick="...">`).

- [Inline JavaScript will not be executed](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)

You will have to do something like this:

file.html

```
<script src="file.js"></script>
...
<form class="text-center" id="searchGuides" action="https://www.arcanumgaming.com/game" method="GET">
     <input type="hidden" name="a" value="search" />
     <input type="hidden" name="g" value="grand-theft-auto-v" />
     <div >
            <input type="text" name="searchVal" class="searchField" placeholder="Search Game Content"  />
     </div>
     <div >
            <a href="#" class="searchBtn">Search Content</a>
     </div>
</form>
```

file.js

```
function clickHandler() {
  document.getElementById('searchGuides').submit();
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
});
```